# How to convert hash to the following form when passing to form in post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some hash like `{ 'a' => 'abc', 'b' => 'def' }`. How can I convert it to `"a=abc&b=def"`?

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'uri'
data = { 'a' => 'abc', 'b' => 'def' }
URI.encode_www_form(data)
```

result:

```
"a=abc&b=def"
```

also works if there are characters that need to be escaped

```
data = { 'a' => '#', 'b' => '&' }
URI.encode_www_form(data)
```

result:

```
"a=%23&b=%26"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, since you're using rails and automatically have the ActiveSupport library, it can be done like this.

```
{ 'a' => 'abc', 'b' => 'def' }.to_param
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
h = { 'a' => 'abc', 'b' => 'def' }
query_string = ''
h.each { |k, v| query_string += "#{k}=#{v}&" } 
query_string[0..-2]
# > "a=abc&b=def"
```